# How do I push an array into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ng2-google-chart

I'm using googles geochart to draw a map with stats but I can't figure out how to combine my 2 arrays

I get this from the server.

```
[["DZ", 0], ["EG", 0], ["EH", 0], ["LY", 0], ["MA", 0], ["SD", 0], ["SS", 0], ["TN", 0], ["BF", 0], ["BJ", 0], ["CI", 0], ["CV", 0], ["GH", 0], ["GM", 0], ["GN", 0], ["GW", 0], ["LR", 0], ["ML", 0], ["MR", 0], ["NE", 0], ["NG", 0], ["SH", 0], ["SL", 0], ["SN", 0], ["TG", 0], ["AO", 0], ["CD", 0], ["ZR", 0], ["CF", 0], ["CG", 0], ["CM", 0], ["GA", 0], ["GQ", 0], ["ST", 0], ["TD", 0], ["BI", 0], ["DJ", 0], ["ER", 0], ["ET", 0], ["KE", 0], ["KM", 0], ["MG", 0], ["MU", 0], ["MW", 0], ["MZ", 0], ["RE", 0], ["RW", 0], ["SC", 0], ["SO", 0], ["TZ", 0], ["UG", 0], ["YT", 0], ["ZM", 0], ["ZW", 0], ["BW", 0], ["LS", 0], ["NA", 0], ["SZ", 0], ["ZA", 0], ["GG", 0], ["JE", 0], ["AX", 0], ["DK", 0], ["EE", 0], ["FI", 0], ["FO", 0], ["GB", 0], ["IE", 0], ["IM", 0], ["IS", 0], ["LT", 0], ["LV", 0], ["NO", 0], ["SE", 0], ["SJ", 0], ["AT", 0], ["BE", 0], ["CH", 0], ["DE", 1], ["DD", 0], ["FR", 0], ["FX", 0], ["LI", 0], ["LU", 0], ["MC", 0], ["NL", 0], ["BG", 0], ["BY", 0], ["CZ", 0], ["HU", 0], ["MD", 0], ["PL", 0], ["RO", 0], ["RU", 0], ["SU", 0], ["SK", 0], ["UA", 0], ["AD", 0], ["AL", 0], ["BA", 0], ["ES", 0], ["GI", 0], ["GR", 0], ["HR", 0], ["IT", 0], ["ME", 0], ["MK", 0], ["MT", 0], ["RS", 0], ["PT", 0], ["SI", 0], ["SM", 0], ["VA", 0], ["YU", 0], ["BM", 0], ["CA", 0], ["GL", 0], ["PM", 0], ["US", 0], ["AG", 0], ["AI", 0], ["AN", 0], ["AW", 0], ["BB", 0], ["BL", 0], ["BS", 0], ["CU", 0], ["DM", 0], ["DO", 0], ["GD", 0], ["GP", 0], ["HT", 0], ["JM", 0], ["KN", 0], ["KY", 0], ["LC", 0], ["MF", 0], ["MQ", 0], ["MS", 0], ["PR", 0], ["TC", 0], ["TT", 0], ["VC", 0], ["VG", 0], ["VI", 0], ["BZ", 0], ["CR", 0], ["GT", 0], ["HN", 0], ["MX", 0], ["NI", 0], ["PA", 0], ["SV", 0], ["AR", 0], ["BO", 0], ["BR", 0], ["CL", 0], ["CO", 0], ["EC", 0], ["FK", 0], ["GF", 0], ["GY", 0], ["PE", 0], ["PY", 0], ["SR", 0], ["UY", 0], ["VE", 0], ["TM", 0], ["TJ", 0], ["KG", 0], ["KZ", 0], ["UZ", 0], ["CN", 0], ["HK", 0], ["JP", 0], ["KP", 0], ["KR", 0], ["MN", 0], ["MO", 0], ["TW", 0], ["AF", 0], ["BD", 0], ["BT", 0], ["IN", 0], ["IR", 0], ["LK", 0], ["MV", 0], ["NP", 0], ["PK", 0], ["BN", 0], ["ID", 0], ["KH", 0], ["LA", 0], ["MM", 0], ["BU", 0], ["MY", 0], ["PH", 0], ["SG", 0], ["TH", 0], ["TL", 0], ["TP", 0], ["VN", 0], ["AE", 0], ["AM", 0], ["AZ", 0], ["BH", 0], ["CY", 0], ["GE", 0], ["IL", 0], ["IQ", 0], ["JO", 0], ["KW", 0], ["LB", 0], ["OM", 0], ["PS", 0], ["QA", 0], ["SA", 0], ["NT", 0], ["SY", 0], ["TR", 0], ["YE", 0], ["YD", 0], ["AU", 0], ["NF", 0], ["NZ", 0], ["FJ", 0], ["NC", 0], ["PG", 0], ["SB", 0], ["VU", 0], ["FM", 0], ["GU", 0], ["KI", 0], ["MH", 0], ["MP", 0], ["NR", 0], ["PW", 0], ["AS", 0], ["CK", 0], ["NU", 0], ["PF", 0], ["PN", 0], ["TK", 0], ["TO", 0], ["TV", 0], ["WF", 0], ["WS", 0]]
```

and I need to put it into this array

```
geoArray = [["Country", "Clicks"]];
```

This is my current code

```
async function drawRegionsMap() {
  geoArray = [["Country", "Clicks"]];

  await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:80/grab`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: token,
      key: "grab_geo_stats",
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
        geoArray.push(data.message[i]);
      }

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(geoArray);

      var options = {
        legend: "none",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        datalessRegionColor: "#62bcfc",
        colors: "#527aff",
        width: "695",
        height: "390",
        interactive: true,
        tooltip: {
          isHtml: true,
        },
      };

      chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
        document.getElementById("regions_div")
      );
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

It should look like this

```
[
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

```js
geoArray.push(...someData);
```

`someData` is here the data you want to put in the `geoArray` array.

Let say `someData` is `[["A", 0], ["B", 0]]`, as `push` takes an infinite number of arguments, what it will do it's that it will unwrap the content of `someData` and only returns the items on the array.

It's like writing the following code:

```js
geoArray.push(["A", 0], ["B", 0]);
```

Comment: Now it's like this
```
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 399]
[400 … 499]
[500 … 599]
[600 … 699]
[700 … 799]
[800 … 899]
[900 … 999]
[1000 … 1099]
[1100 … 1199]
[1200 … 1299]
[1300 … 1399]
```

It needs to be like this
```
['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
```

Comment: @AkselGlyholt - Maybe throw us a bone and tell us what you *want* the result to look like?

Comment: It should look like this          
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]

Comment: So you want to merge `[['Country', 'Popularity']]` with `[['Germany', 200], ['United States', 300], ['Brazil', 400], ['Canada', 500], ['France', 600], ['RU', 700]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

For combing multiple arrays into the single array do something like ->

```js
const combinedArray = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arrN];
```

So assuming that the data you get back as a response is an `Array` then you can do,

```js
const mapData = [...geoArray, ...data];
```

This will merge your both arrays into on single array!

Answer (score 0):

To push the response data in the end of geoData array insted of doing

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
        geoArray.push(data.message[i]);
```

you can replace it with

```
geoArray.push(...data)
```